# Alternate option for VC++ comapared to 2008 &2010

Tags: visual-c++

In VC++ 2008 version I have the option `Properties > C/C++ > general > Detect 64-bit Portability Issues`.

But in the VC++ 2010 this option does not exist. Is there any alternate for that?

Comment: It was *deprecated*, not removed, they did not want to maintain the feature anymore.  With the recommended workaround "just target x64 to find portability issues".  It did get removed eventually: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2014/06/13/compiler-switch-deprecationremoval-changes-in-visual-studio-14/

Comment: @HansPassant Should this be provided as an answer so the question ca be closed?